# Restrict sys.databases view to connectable databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, availability-group

How to restrict the results from `sys.databases` to available databases?

We are changing to availability groups and replica server running on sql-server 2017.

Before this I had a select statement running on master-database to see which datebases are running on the server (`select name, state from sys.databases`) and then let the user select a database and setup a connection to the database for further sql-statements.

But now on the new system with availability groups and replica-server, I see more databases, which I cannot connect to, when I open a connection to single availability group.

The select statements shows all databases even if they belong to another availability group (they are hosted by the same replica-server).

The problem is that for an dbo its no problem to figured out which databases belongs to the availability group (`sys.availabiltiy` - Views), but the normal user doesn't have the needed rights to view these sys-Views and I don't want to give him `view_server_stats` role.

Comment: If I understand your question you are asking if you can change the sys.databases view to only show databases to which the current user has connect access? AFAIK that isn't possible.

Comment: I don't want to change the view, but if possible join the sys.databases view with another one, or use a where-filter to select only the available databases for this availability group

Comment: Tough nut to crack, because a view won't work either -- you'll get "the module being executed is not trusted" if you try to join up something like `availability_databases_cluster`. Ownership chaining won't save you there. Nor will a table-valued function (on its own). A signed sproc might work... a lot of effort just to get that info to unprivileged users.